# regex for minimum 8 character,beside letters add number or symbol or both

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

Examples which should Satisfy:
test@1234 (accept)
TestTo^12 (accept)
test!5655(accept)
Test!@$&(accept)
testtesttest(should not accept)
Beside Letter i want atleast one number or symbol.If both is available that is fine.

Comment: Any effort so far ? please post the tried code

Comment: You should just Google something like "password regex" and you will find plenty of examples that meet your needs.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated with a one-regex solution:**

Because *any character* could be the one that is non-alphabetic, testing for 8 characters and ensuring that at least one of them isn't alphabetic simultaneously requires a bit more complex regular expression. The "dumb and straight-forward" solution is to use a lot of "OR" operations for the 8 possibilities:

- The first character is not alphabetic
- The second character is not alphabetic
- The third character is not alphabetic
- ...

It would look like so:

```
var myRegex = /([^A-Za-z].{7})|(.[^A-Za-z].{6})|(.{2}[^A-Za-z].{5})|(.{3}[^A-Za-z].{4})|(.{4}[^A-Za-z].{3})|(.{5}[^A-Za-z].{2})|(.{6}[^A-Za-z].)|(.{7}[^A-Za-z])/
```

A smarter solution uses [Regular Expression look-ahead operations](https://javascript.info/regexp-lookahead-lookbehind). We basically match an empty string followed by 8 characters, so long as that empty string is followed by a pattern that contains (anywhere within it) a non-alphabetic character:

```
var myRegex = /(?=.*[^A-Za-z]).{8}/;
```

Look-aheads can make regular expessions more difficult to understand and debug, so it's sometimes better to rephrase the problem as a multi-part check (e.g. first check for 8 characters, ***then*** check for a non-alphabetic character). Thus, my original answer:

**Original (and still totally valid):**

It may not be the preferred solution, but this would probably be easiest to solve with two regular expressions:

```
var myValue = "testtesttest";
if (
    /.{8}/.test(myValue) &&
    /[^A-Za-z]/.test(myValue)
)
{
    // At least 8 characters and contains one non-alphabetic character
}
else
{
    // One of the two tests failed
}
```

Of course `/.{8}/.test(myValue)` is just `myValue.length >= 8` which runs a lot faster and is easier to read:

```
if (
    myValue.length >= 8 &&
    /[^A-Za-z]/.test(myValue)
)
...
```

A note on password security:

**Complex passwords are not secure passwords**

Let me reiterate:

## Complex passwords are not secure passwords

When a password is complex, people can't remember it. Because they can't remember it they either have to use a password management tool (if they're smart) or, more likely, ***they write it down on a post-it note***. But it gets worse. When you require symbols and numbers it becomes hard to type a password, so people often make them as short as possible. You limit it to 8 characters? **Their password will be 8 characters**. But ***it gets worse***. Many people, to make passwords more memorable, follow some pattern like:

- Take a word and tack on a number ("honeybee326")
- Take a word and replace some letters with symbols ("unf@th0m@ble")
- Take a word and tack on a symbol ("mypassword!")

People trying to guess a password don't need to try ***every possible combination of letters, numbers, and symbols***. They just need to try these patterns. This greatly reduces the time it takes to crack passwords.

Any security expert who actually knows their stuff will tell you: the secret to a strong password is a ***long password***. This means:

> Hello my name is Steven and I like security

is 99999999x more secure than:

> 8j3@vk;8]

Instead of testing for symbols or numbers, I recommend just putting a large length requirement (something like 15 characters) if you want to ***really*** keep people secure. Or, just tell them what you recommend and let them do what they feel is best (if they choose a bad passwords, only they suffer the consequences). Unless this is an admin password, in which case enforce a massive length.

Comment: it's better to use `myValue.length === 8` than `/.{8}/.test(myValue)`when you're using two seperate regexes

Comment: @CodeManiac Very good point. I was thinking in regex-land and derp'd

Comment: Hi first regex big one is working in almost all scenarios but for few its not working like testtest1,testtest@.....Can you just help me with that ??

Comment: @riyatolia When I type `/([^A-Za-z].{7})|(.[^A-Za-z].{6})|(.{2}[^A-Za-z].{5})|(.{3}[^A-Za-z].{4})|(.{4}[^A-Za-z].{3})|(.{5}[^A-Za-z].{2})|(.{6}[^A-Za-z].)|(.{7}[^A-Za-z])/.test("testtest1,testtest@")` into the Google Chrome console it seems to work (returns `true`). Where are you using it that it is not working?